# Discord.py Взаимодействие с кнопками в одном канале

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Если задать несколько задач через команду
!задача дата текст_задачи
то появятся в нужном канале все задачи. Но если у любой из них нажать на кнопку взаимодействия, то у других задач кнопки уже работать не будут. Прошу подсказать как это исправить. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку удалялась конкретная задача, на которой нажали кнопку и чтобы кнопки у других задач работали. Не могу понять как это сделать.

```py
@bot.command(name="задание", aliases=['задача'])
async def task_day(ctx: commands.Context, date: str = None, *task: str) -> None:
  await ctx.message.delete()                                              # удаляем сообщение автора задачи
  if date is None:
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
      description='**:grey_exclamation: Обязательно укажи дату! Пример команды: \n!задача 01.01.2000 твое задание**'))
    return
  elif not task:
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
      description='**:grey_exclamation: Обязательно укажи задание! Пример команды: \n!задача 01.01.2000 твое задание**'))
    return
  category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name="Задачи")        # пытаемся получить категорию с именем Задачи
  if not category:                                                        # если такой нет, то
      category = await ctx.guild.create_category(name="Задачи")            # создаем категорию
  task = " ".join(task)
  date = date.replace(".", "-")                                            # заменяем в дате все точки знаками тире
  channel = discord.utils.get(category.channels, name=date)                # работаем с категорией
  if not channel:                                                          # если нет канала с именем аргумента data
      channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(date, category=category)  # создаем такой канал
  await channel.send(                                                         # шлем туда сообщение
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Новая задача!", description=task, colour=0x4169E1),
    components=[[
      Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label='Готово'),
      Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Отказываюсь')
    ]]
  )
  response = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
  if response.channel == channel:
    if response.component.label == 'Готово':
      await response.respond(content='Отлично!')
      await ctx.message.delete()
      channel = bot.get_channel(951917790518988830)  # куда шлем отчеты о выполнении задач
      await channel.send(
      embed=discord.Embed(title='Задача выполнена!', description=(f'**{response.user.display_name}** подтвердил выполнение задачи **"{task}"**. Задача закрыта.' ), colour=0x4169E1)
      )
    elif response.component.label == 'Отказываюсь':
      await response.respond(content='Принято!')
      await ctx.message.delete()
      channel = bot.get_channel(951917790518988830)  # куда шлем отчеты о выполнении задач
      await channel.send(
      embed=discord.Embed(title='Задача НЕ выполнена!', description=(f'**{response.user.display_name}** отказался от выполнения задачи **"{task}"**. Задача закрыта.' ), colour=0x4169E1)
      )
```

```py
  await channel.send(                                                         # шлем туда сообщение
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Новая задача!", description=task, colour=0x4169E1),
    components=[[
      Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label='Готово', custom_id=f"{ctx.id}:ready"),
      Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Отказываюсь', custom_id=f"{ctx.id}:close")
    ]]
  )
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Ignoring exception in command задание:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/DiscordGarwinVRN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 103, in task_day
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label='Готово', custom_id=f"{ctx.id}:ready"),
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/DiscordGarwinVRN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/DiscordGarwinVRN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/DiscordGarwinVRN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавляй custom_id в параметры кнопки. Туда ты можешь впихнуть id сообщения.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее? Я не силен в discord.py

Comment: `components=[[
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label='Готово', custom_id=f"{ctx.id}:ready"),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Отказываюсь', custom_id=f"{ctx.id}:close")
]]`
Так лучше?

Comment: и ещё важно - custom_id не должны быть одинаковыми.

Comment: Не получилось. Сделал как у Вас в примере, прикрепил кусок кода, но при попытке выполнить команду получаю ошибку. Ее тоже прикрепил. Говорит нет такого атрибута.

Comment: Попробуй кнопки сделать class'ом.
А вообще лучше перейти на py-cord, у них удобнее.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNUuYEWGOxA&ab_channel=CodeWithSwastik

Comment: у меня уже достаточно много кода использует библиотеку, которую я начал использовать изначально, поэтому переход на другую библиотеку не вариант.